# Google Apps Scripts for Creating a Folder Structure

Tags: automation, scripting

I'm a total newb when it comes to thins like this and I'm trying to do pretty much the same thing.  I've found Google Apps Scripts (yay for me :-) and now I'm actually trying to get this working the first time.  So I've populated this text into the first window and then I click deploy?  I'm a bit lost.  Can you help a newb out?

Secondly, I'm trying to create a scripts when triggered, it creates a file structure

Main Dir = CLIENT_Name
Subdirectories = Photos, Plans, Proposals, Material Selections

This folder structure should be created in a folder already in my Google drive.

How would this change the above script, and how do I actually got about triggering this script?

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: I thought that in your question, when you provide your current script and explain the current issue of your script, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.